# how to set random value as defaultValue for text input.

Tags: admin-on-rest

I want to set a dynamic (random) value as defaultValue for textInput in simpleform. I did the code like below

```
<TextInput
source="ctr.uid"
label="UID"
defaultValue={() =>
  Math.random()
    .toString(36)
    .substring(2, 5) + new Date().getTime().toString(36)} />
```

I can able to see the random values but when user clicks on save the entire form is reset to empty fields. How to fix this issue?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue on the create post form in this codesandbox but it seems to work. Can you confirm ? https://codesandbox.io/s/p7462x6nx7

Comment: You can see that all the fields get empty when you click on save and title field also generated a new value.

Comment: Yes but they are saved correctly anyway so what's the prb ?